# SQL String Fuzzy Matching. Array or Concatenation?

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-matching

I have a sizable list of places and many of them have multiple names. I want to implement a fuzzy search for them.

Is it better to **concatenate** all the names into one string or put them all in an **array**?

**Concatenation**

```
--table definition
CREATE TABLE places_concat(
  id serial,
  name varchar(200),
  all_names varchar(10000),
  ...
);
--sql query
select name from places where 'kugluktuk' % all_names;
```

**Array**

```
--table definition
CREATE TABLE places_array(
  id serial,
  name varchar(200),
  all_names text[],
  ...
);
--sql query
select name from places where 'kugluktuk' % any(all_names);
```

(I'm using postgres 10 with the [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) extension so `%` fuzzy matches strings.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will not be an overkill for you but I had similar task with matching some descriptions using pg_trgm extension. Problem was also similar - it was possible to have more descriptions for one case.

After some tests I created solution which for each case creates one concatenated string constructed as a list of distinct words from all descriptions for given case.

And I test "similarity" of this unique description to the given search string. Problem with trigram is that string containing the same words several times has lower similarity rate against testing string then description containing only distinct words....

And to be even more precise I had at the end also pre-process "searching string" to remove possible repeated words even from it... People sometimes enter unbelievable things... :-)

Comment: I don't want the similarity to all the names, I just need to see if at least one of them matches.